# In Access SQL, is there anyway to use user input as the field name?

Tags: sql, ms-access, dynamic

I have a database with a table whose field names are date (e.g., Jan, Feb...). Is there any way that I can ask the input from users to return a certain column?

For example, there will be a pop-up window so that user can type "Jan" in order to generate a single column with the name of Jan?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [Switch](https://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) function for this.

```
SELECT Switch (
    [Select month] = "Jan", Jan, -- if user enters Jan, use the column Jan
    [Select month] = "Feb", Feb  -- if user enters Feb, use the column Feb
    ) AS Month
from YourTable
```

`[Select month]`is the prompt that will be shown.

Running this query in Access will show a prompt and select column based on input.

Comment: That's building one on one relationship between user inputs and column names. Is there anyway that I can still realize this function even if column names will be changed due to regular updating? Thanks!

Comment: @Lavender612 I don't think you can do this directly in SQL with Access (it would be possible with MS SQL Server though), but it is possible to accomplish using a form with VBA code. This link has some information about that: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/304302